# Using Arrays in GAS

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I am completely baffled.  I want to create arrays from cell ranges on a spreadsheet.  The 2D array works fine. But when I try to address an element in the 1D array I get a  "null" return.  I have tried to do the same thing with an array defined within the script and it works fine.

Here is my code

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Availability');  
  var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('working');    
  var sheet3 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Players');  
  var sheet4 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Fixtures')  
  var totfours = 68;
  var totplayers = 22;
  var r = sheet4.getRange(2,4,totfours,4);
  var fullset = r.getValues();
  Logger.log(fullset[8][2]);
  //var players = sheet4.getRange(totfours + 4, 2, 1, totplayers).getValues();
  //Logger.log (players, players [3]);
  var players = sheet4.getRange(77,2,1,5).getValues();
  Logger.log(players);
  Logger.log(players[2]);
  
  
  
  
}
```

This is the log

```
[20-08-19 14:09:55:866 PDT] Dave W
[20-08-19 14:09:55:955 PDT] [[aa, ab, ac, ad, ae]]
[20-08-19 14:09:55:957 PDT] null
```

I am new to GAS and have spent days trying to figure this out!

Comment: `players` only has one element in it. Did you mean `players[0][2]` which will be "ac"?

Comment: A range is always 2D. It's never 1D.

Comment: @MariosKaramanis `players` logs `[[aa, ab, ac, ad, ae]]`. It has data.

Comment: Thank you.  Issue resolved.  I didn't realise that arrays could only be 2D